# php subclass how to append data into parrent's static variable?

Tags: php

subclass how to append data into parent's static variable in PHP?

for example:

```
class Error {
    public static $messages = [
        200 => 'OK',
    ];
}
```

And subclass:

```
class SubError extends Error {
    // how to append some data into $messages instead of overwrite,
    // such as 404 => 'Not Found', and then SubError::$messages got:
    // [200=>'OK', 404=>'Not Found']
}
```

Is it possible in PHP, or some trick?

Comment: Can you try `Error::messages = 404` ?

Comment: @JaydeepMor No, I would like to got 200 and 404 in SubError::$messages

Comment: take a look to http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php